# Baidu Android Store automatically installed without permission

Tags: permissions, htc-sensation-xe

Android Store (com.baidu.androidstore) is automatically installed on my device without permission. It happens in last 2 weeks. Two months ago, I had installed Baidu Browser (com.baidu.browser.inter) but had uninstalled it 1 month later.

What I did to solve:

- Unknown sources option unchecked
- Uninstall the app
- Reboot the phone

But after few hours it get automatically installed again.

Did anyone here have the same problem? How to solve this?

Device: HTC Sensation XE
OS: ICS 4.0.3
Rooted: Yes

Comment: You'll need to delete the apk from the (I think I'm right here, anyone want to chime in?) /system folder after you uninstall it. You can do this with a file explorer as you are rooted. It happens on Samsung devices with Samsung apps. I'm trying to find it here for you myself, but I'm sure a search of the app will turn up the apk somewhere. That's what reinstalls on boot.

Comment: @RossC I didn't found any apk on my sdcard/internal

Comment: It'll be buried in the /system folder more than likely.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

1. If your device is rooted, install 'Root Browser' from Google Play
2. Now go in the phone directory, and browse to `/data/data/com.baidu.browser.inter`.
3. Select and delete it.
4. Restart phone and you will never be bothered again by Baidu browser again.

Source: Experimented myself on Android tablet.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing with my Lenovo K3 Note.

1. Installed Root Browser.
2. Found `com.baidu.browser.inter` in:

   - `/storage/sdcard0/Android/data`
   - `/storage/sdcard1/Android/data`
   - `/storage/emulated/Android/data`
3. Erase it
4. I searched for all Baidu files and deleted them, but I'm not sure how good is to do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having same issue with Baidu and Du battery installer. They keep coming back.

**A temporary solution** is to disable them. On resetting the device, they automatically install. I was able to locate the files by going in settings>Apps>All. There you can see `com.baidu.browser.inter` (Baidu Browser) and `com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay` (DU Speed Booster) and `com.dianxinos.dxbs` (DU Battery Saver), and can "disable" them (open their entries, tap the button labeled "disable"). *To really delete them, it requires root access on the device.*

<sup>(italic part edited in by Izzy)</sup>